# SSRS parameter default to most recent 1st April

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have a requirement for an SSRS parameter that will be for a start date of the most 1st April, so today it will report from 1/4/2015 with 10 weeks data, but after the 1/4/16 it will default to 1/4/16.

Can anyone help with this please?

I can find most recent month, or current month etc, but this one is a little tricky.  Thankyou.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and  Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression:

```
=IIF(Today() >= DateSerial(Year(Today()), 4, 1), DateSerial(Year(Today()), 4, 1), DateSerial(Year(Today()) - 1, 4, 1))
```

The idea is to check if the 1st of April of the current year has been reached (`Today() >= DateSerial(Year(Today()), 4, 1)`).

- If yes, take the 1st of April of the current year: `DateSerial(Year(Today()), 4, 1)`
- If no, take the 1st of April of the previous year: `DateSerial(Year(Today()) - 1, 4, 1)`

Comment: Sebastien that is such an elegant yet simple expression, and of course works perfectly.  I am kicking myself because I should have written that myself!  Thankyou for your time.